# Is their any way to select the connection profile Manager when compiling from the command line with MSBuild?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is their any way to select the connection profile Manager when compiling from the command line with MSBuild? especially for iOS deployment?

I always need to open delphi, select release, build the project (and I always lost 8 min of my life here), deploy it, save and close it, then I can run the command line :

```
MSBuild %ProjectDir%\MyApp.dproj /p:Config=Release /p:Platform=iOSDevice64 /t:Build;Deploy
```

else I have error when running directly the command line :( I don't know what Delphi does in the background when I build and deploy the app in release, but seam it's set somewhere some settings that will make MSBuild working

Comment: Going by the .targets files, it *appears* to be: /p:Profile=[path_to_profile], where [path_to_profile] could be something like: %APPDATA%\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Mac.profile. I've never done this myself, and don't have time to test right now :-)

Comment: @DaveNottage I just try with /p:Profile=[path_to_profile] I have the error C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(603,5): error : Missing provisioning information. Distribution certificate has not been specified for the "AppStore" platform configuration.

Comment: See my reply to your report on QP: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-28051

Comment: @DaveNottage You reply in quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-28051 ? I can't see your reply :(

Comment: I meant my first reply. I see you have additional trouble

Comment: @DaveNottage ooh ah ok, so as i answer it's still not work :( :(